# We're better vs It's better vs Better

Tags: grammar

I did some research online. It seems that I should say "we're better **doing** something", "it's better **to do** something", and "better **do** something".  Is this correct? Why are there differences in terms of the verb forms?

> We're better not **trying** to challenge him.

> It's better not **to try** to challenge him.

> Better not **try** to challenge him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third one is easy to account for: it's aphetic for *You'd better not try to challenge him* - base form of *try* after the modal *'d* (*would*)

The others are a little harder to explain, but it can still be done.

The first answers the question "how are we better?" The answer is a phrase that qualifies "we" - in this case a participial phrase *We're better [not trying to challenge him]*.

The second one answers the question "What is better", and the answer is a noun phrase, specifically an infinitive clause. "What is better? Not to try to challenge him".

I think both of these constructions could use either of the two forms, but the ones you quote are the most natural choices.